# A Car Class with Speed

Tags: c#

EDIT: I am getting a new error after having added the () to the Car instantiation.
It says:

> 'Car_Class_BBrantley.Form1.myCar()' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial

Alright, so my task is to create an application that displays 3 main features: year, make, and speed of a car. The year and make are inputted with textboxes and the speed starts at 0.

There is an accelerate button which is supposed to add 5 to the speed every time it is pressed and a brake button which decreases the speed by 5 every time it is pressed.

I am having trouble using the class and form together to display the results. I need to display in a messagebox the make, year, and speed. I have been sitting here for hours and I am getting nowhere. I am getting the errors

> speed does not exist in current context

and

> car does not exist in current context

under my buttons. I am unsure of how I should go about fixing this.

Any and all help is much appreciated. I'm sorry if this is a mess. I have never worked with classes before.

Here is the form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Car_Class_BBrantley
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Car myCar;

        public Form1()
        {
            myCar = new Car;

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void GetCarData(Car car)
        {
            try {
            myCar.Make = txtMake.Text;

            myCar.Year = int.Parse(txtModel.Text);

            myCar.Speed = 0;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(string.Concat("Must enter a valid make and year model for the car. ", ex.Message, "\r\n", ex.StackTrace));
            } 
        }

        private void btnAcc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetCarData();
            myCar.AccSpeed(5);
            MessageBox.Show(" Your car is a " + myCar.Year + myCar.Make + " and it is     traveling " + myCar.Speed + " mph. ");
        }

        private void btnBrake_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetCarData();
            myCar.DecSpeed(5);
            MessageBox.Show(" Your car is a " + myCar.Year + myCar.Make + " and it is     traveling " + myCar.Speed + " mph. ");
        }
    }
}
```

If you would like to see the class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Car_Class_BBrantley
{
    class Car
    {
    private int year;
    private string make;
    private int speed;

    public Car()
    {
        this.year = 1994;
        this.make = "Ford";
        this.speed = 0;
    }

    public Car(string make, int year, int speed)
    {
        this.year = year;
        this.make = make;
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    public string Make
    {
        get { return make; }
        set { make = value; }
    }

    public int Year
    {
        get { return Year; }
        set { Year = value; }
    }

    public int Speed
    {
        get { return speed; }
        set { speed = value; }
    }

    public void AccSpeed(int speedIncrement)
    {
        //Add check for speed limit ranges
        Speed += speedIncrement;
    }

    public void DecSpeed(int speedDecrement)
    {
        //Add check for speed limit ranges
        Speed -= speedDecrement;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: From the SO help center: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: When you get those errors (I'm assuming they are runtime errors?) what line does it indicate is causing the problem.  This is important.

Comment: Here is the only error now. 'Car_Class_BBrantley.Form1.myCar()' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial (it is line 14)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're instantiating your `Car` class incorrectly:

```
myCar = new Car;   // wrong

myCar = new Car();
```

You're not passing your `Car` instance to the `GetCarData()` method even though it expects it:

```
GetCarData();      // wrong

GetCarData(myCar);
```

*(You're not actually using the instance of* `Car` *that you're passing to the method... either remove the parameter from the method, or reference it in your code.)*

Answer (score 0):

1-You are not using parentheses in the Car constructor:

```
myCar = new Car;
```

should be

```
myCar = new Car();
```

2-You declared GetCarData to expect a parameter but it's not using it and when you call it you are not passing it.

Change

```
private void GetCarData(Car car)
```

To

```
private void GetCarData()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  parentheses within your class name to create an instance of the class:

```
myCar = new Car();
```

And change your method definition to:

```
private void GetCarData()
```

The method expecting a parameter of type `Car`, but you are calling it without providing any parameter.As far as I can see you are not using the parameter in the method so you can just remove it.Otherwise you have to pass a `Car` instance to your method.